# Is multi-level ConcurrentDictionary still thread-safe?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, concurrency, parallel-extensions

I have four level data structure defined like this:

```
Dictionary<Type1, Dictionary<Type2, Dictionary<Type3, List<Type4>>>>
```

The whole thing is encapsulated in a class which also maintains thread-safety. Currently it just locks whole collection while it reads/manipulates the data (reading is by orders of magnitude more common than writing).

I was thinking of replacing the `Dictionary` with [`ConcurrentDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx) and `List` with [`ConcurrentBag`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381779.aspx) (its items don't have to be ordered).

If I do so, can I just eliminate the locks and be sure the concurrent collections will do their job correctly?

Comment: The concurrent collections *will* do their jobs properly, but that data structure looks insane!

Comment: Are you sure you don't want a `ConcurrentDictionary<Tuple<TKey1,TKey2,TKey2>,TValue>`?

Comment: @CodeInChaos See my comment to Mania's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The concurrent collections will prevent data corruption and crashes, but the code won't be semantically equivalent to your current one. For example, if you iterate one of the concurrent dictionaries, [some of the items may belong to different updates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287131.aspx):

> The enumerator returned from the
>   dictionary is safe to use concurrently
>   with reads and writes to the
>   dictionary, however it does not
>   represent a moment-in-time snapshot of
>   the dictionary. The contents exposed
>   through the enumerator may contain
>   modifications made to the dictionary
>   after GetEnumerator was called.

If you want to maintain the exact behavior you have now, yet save on the cost of locking, you may want to lock with [ReaderWriterLockSlim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.aspx) which is especially suited for cases with more reads than writes.

Comment: I think `ReaderWriterLockSlim` has a relatively large overhead, so it's often not optimal for many quick operations, even if most of them are reads.

Answer (score 6):

I'm nearly a year late to the question.. but just in case anyone finds themselves in a similar position to Matěj Zábský, ask yourself:

Can you use a `Dictionary<Tuple<Type1, Type2, Type3>, List<Type4>>` instead?

Considerably easier to work with, and considering that hash tables (ie Dictionaries) are O(1) data structures with a somewhat hefty constant component (even more so if you move to a `ConcurrentDictionary`) it'd likely perform faster too. It'd also use less memory, and be pretty trivial to convert to a `ConcurrentDictionary`.

Of course if you need to enumerate all of a given `Type2` for a given `Type1` key, the nested dictionaries is possibly the way to go. But is that a requirement?

Comment: I definitely agree having Dictionary with Tuple key is better than nested dictionaries, but I found the nested nature of my solution useful (I could remove all items with L1 key X simply by removing one dictionary - O(1) instead of O(N), all items with a combination of L1 and L2 keys by removing one L2 dictionary...). However this may not often be the case, of course. +1